# NameError: name 'name' is not defined telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I want to launch my experimental store. OS centos 7, python 3.8.
I run the script "python3 bot.py" :

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters

TOKEN = '***'

def start(update, context):
    message = f"Hello {update.message.from_user.first_name}, welcome to our shop! Please select a product from the list:\n"
    message += "1. Product 1\n"
    message += "2. Product 2\n"
    message += "3. Product 3\n"
    message += "4. Product 4\n"
    message += "5. Product 5\n"
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=message)

def echo(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=update.message.text)

if name == '__main__':
    updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & (~Filters.command), echo))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
```

and get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 17, in <module>
    if name == 'main':
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

Tell me, please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you mean `__name__ == "__main__"`? The traceback and code also don't seem to be matching up.

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that you have used `name` instead of `__name__` in the if statement that checks if the script is being executed as the main program. The correct syntax for this statement is `if __name__ == "__main__":`